# visual studio builds wrong project

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently moving a series of VS2005 32 bit solutions into VS2015 (update 3) for 64 bit implementation.  The solution in question consists of 3 VB projects, 14 Fortran projects and one Assembler project.

When I build this solution, all projects are processed as expected.  However, if I attempt to individually build any of the first three projects listed in the Solution Explorer pane, a different project is built.

This only happens for the first three projects in the list (all Fortran projects).  The project that is actually built is always the same one.  It is further down the Solution Explorer list and also a Fortran project.  When I individually build any of the other projects in the solution, they are all built as expected.

I have been unable to find any link between the affected projects and the project which is actually being built and am at a loss understanding how to correct this.

The immediate work-around is to rebuild the entire solution whenever I need to rebuild one of the affected projects, however this requires somewhat more processing (and delay) than ideal.

Has anyone else encountered such a problem, and is there a simple fix?

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: Fortran in Visual Studio is not provided by Microsoft. It seems that for any related issues you should report to whoever develops that support. Very likely they don't support Visual Studio 2015 (and latest MSBuild) very well, and only they can fix that for you.

Comment: Thanks @Lex.  Fortran is maintained in VS2015 by Intel.  (VS2017 is not yet supported.)  As the projects affected are all Fortran this indeed may be their problem.  I have subsequently found that the projects build correctly if using the Solution Explorer context menu "Project Only+Build Only ..."  This doesn't resolve the original problem, but is a much nicer work-around.